# currency arbitrage and matrix

Tags: currency

I am very new to the field of quants but i was just wondering if matrices can be used to identify the arbitrage opportunity available in multi currency conversions. It would be sort of a shortest path finding problem or minimum cost algorithm used in different other problem sets.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming site, not finance.

Comment: @suslik this is algorithmic question, not finance

Comment: This is clearly a real question.  If you want to close it as off-topic, that's a different matter.  It might be better on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://quant.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

This [algorithms book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523402) explains (or hints, since it's an exercise), how to do it using logarithms then a classic shortest path.  It was a fun problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the question "are matrices useful to identify arbitrage opportunities available in multi-currency conversions?", the answer is yes. You would use a matrix to store each conversion rate from currency `i` to currency `j` in cell `(i,j)`.

For the question "would an algorithm that finds such opportunities be similar to a shortest path finding problem?", the answer is also yes. Given the matrix for a problem, you would apply an algorithm that only resembles the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

For a full explanation have a look [here](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/05/26/arbitrage.html).